# Does "The Final Enemy" explain why sahuagin champions are worth fewer victory points than coral smashers?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league, ghosts-of-saltmarsh

"The Final Enemy" from *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* ends with

> the adventurers assaulting a sahuagin stronghold.

The party's success is determined by how many victory points they accrue by killing sahuagin and accomplishing objectives. The exact numbers are as follows (GoS, p. 138):

> ### Victory Points
>
> Sahuagin: 1
>
> Sahuagin champion: 3
>
> Sahuagin coral smasher: 5
>
> Blademaster Makaht: 10
>
> Opening the gate at area 1: 15
>
> Baron Kepmak: 25
>
> Raising no alert: 25

A sahuagin champion is CR 3, while a sahuagin coral smasher is only CR 1 (both on GoS, p. 249). **Does "The Final Enemy" explain why a champion is worth fewer victory points than a (much) weaker coral smasher?**

I am currently running "The Final Enemy" in Adventurers League, so any AL-specific guidance is also acceptable (after stating if the module itself covers this scenario).

Comment: @JohnClifford the coral smashers described in *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* are CR1, not CR3. However, the question isn't about why their CR is what it is; it's about why killing the apparently less-dangerous coral smashers contributes more to the adventurers' mission than killing the significantly more dangerous champions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, it doesn't explain this.

From what I have read in *Ghosts of Saltmarsh*, I do not see any justification for the point values. I also looked back at the original adventure for AD&D to see if maybe there was a legacy justification included in the original incarnation. The original version does not appear to have Victory Points, and there are no Sahuagin coral smashers in that version, either.